# PyQt5 hint display for entire app/window (not for a widget)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I do not know how to phrase it well, but is it possible to have your application to throw out some hint/notification, where it would work same as for setToolTip for a widget, but for whole application possibly? I am looking for something similar to what Windows has when it gives you suggestion how to exit full screen. I am looking something like that.
[image: Windows Hint]